# How to prove this statement is logically equivalent to a tautology?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am studying discrete maths at uni, and i am trying to do some practice tests from the workbook.
One of the questions is:
For each of the following statements, use a truth table to determine whether it is a contradiction,
a tautology or neither. If it is a contradiction or a tautology, verify your answer
using logical equivalences

[image]
I have proven using truth tables that it is indeed a tautology, but i am having dificulty proving using logical equiverlences that it is indeed a tautology.

I was just wondering if someone might be able to give me some hints as to what steps i should take?

thanks

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proposition and its contrapositive are logically equivalent. The contrapositive of $(p \to q)$ is $(\lnot q \to \lnot p)$ and similarly, the contrapositive of $(q \to r)$ is $(\lnot r \to \lnot q)$. Therefore your main proposition can be rewritten as $((\lnot q \to \lnot p) \land (\lnot r \to \lnot q) \land (\lnot r)) \to (\lnot p)$. From there we can see that the left side simplifies to $(\lnot p)$ using the rule of Modus Ponens (refer to the comments below). Now, $(\lnot p) \to (\lnot p)$ is clearly a tautology and so we are done.

Comment: You should explain more about how the left side simplifies to what you claim it does IMO.

Comment: I am using the rule of Modus Ponens. If $P \to Q$ and $P$ is true, then $Q$ is true. Using the example above, we have $(\lnot r) \land (\lnot r \to \lnot q)$ so that simplifies to $(\lnot q)$

Comment: Yeah I know. I'm saying I think that you should maybe include that in your answer because it's clear OP is a beginner. But maybe s/he will see the comment now.

Comment: Hey Vizuna, Thanks heaps for that, it was a huge help. I think i have got it now (fingers crossed). If it is not too much trouble, would you be able to confirm whether this is correct (ie the laws i used are allowed)? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_krkpxyd558aEZPY19fWm9GcEU/view?usp=sharing if not, not worries. Thanks again for your help, Tim :)

Comment: Hi, the first three lines are valid, but the 4th to 6th lines are not. For example, you cannot get from $((q \lor \lnot p) \land (r \lor \lnot q) \land (\lnot r)) \to (\lnot p)$ to $((\lnot p) \land (r) \land (\lnot r)) \to (\lnot p)$. In particular, $(q \lor \lnot p)$ does not simplify to $(\lnot p)$. There is no rule which allows you to do that. You might have confused it with $(q \land \lnot p)$, which in this case *can* be simplified to $(\lnot p)$.